# Available CSS properties in UITextView/NSAttributedString

Tags: css, uitextview, nsattributedstring, styling

I'm trying to change a `UITextView`'s text appearance using `NSAttributedString` and CSS. It looks like not all CSS attributes are supported. For example, I can change the text color, but not the margins. **Is there a complete collection of supported CSS properties? And if so, where?** I wasn't able to find anything in the developer documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, and maybe because there are quite a lot of CSS properties, there is no documentation giving which are supported with NSAttributedString or not. They add sometimes new support I think (from what I remember bullet list weren't always supported).

Comment: Were you able to find anything?